# How to determine the Java JDK version and sdk version?

Tags: java

I am having "Eclipse IDE for JAVA Developers" and runtime environment 6.0. My question is how can i determine my SDK version and JDk version.

And also help on how to add bouncy castle to work with my eclipse.

Comment: Please split your questions (ie, 'how to determine JDK version' and 'how to add bouncy castle') into separate threads.

Answer (score 3):

`java -version` will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

`javac -version` will tell the default JDK version and theoretically it can be different from what you get with `java -version` if you have both JDK and JRE on the same machine (and it can get more tricky when you have more than one JDK on same machine.. just try to avoid it). Also, please note that in case of Eclipse there's such thing (plug-in) as JDT, which has its own Java compiler.

Answer (score -1):

After placing `bin` in your PATH open `cmd` and type **`java -version`**

Comment: You don't need to set CLASSPATH; you do need to have the Java /bin in your PATH for it to work.  You should not have a CLASSPATH environment variable set at all.  Use the -classpath argument for javac.exe and java.exe.

Comment: @ duffymo oh..Thank you.There was a bit of confusion.